# Unit test generation error in Visual studio website project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, web

I have been trying to generate unit tests in a website solution but it keeps giving me error like "Test generation is only supported on non test projects".

I am able to generate unit test cases in a web application project but same is not possible for a website.

I am using Visual studio 2010 professional.

Comment: Can you give more information about at which point the error occurs?

Comment: @Amber... The error occurs when i right click on any method body to generate unit test cases..

Comment: I am having a similar issue.  In my case the right-click menu doesn't even show up, but if I type `EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.CreateUnitTests` in the command window I get the error above.