# How does Visual Studio 2010 determine which projects are test projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

I have a project made recently by a team member.  I added some classes and wanted to unit test them.  I added the project to our unit test solution, but I can't right-click on any function and select "Create Unit Test".  I found a solution to manually type `EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.CreateUnitTests` in the command window, but then I get an error "Test generation is only supported on non test projects."

I searched for "test" through the whole project and only came up with `PopulateStructure` so there's no functions with test attributes.  I deleted a stray reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` which the team member said had been automatically inserted by Visual Studio.  The reference did not come back when I compiled, but I still couldn't auto generate tests.

I searched for `[` and the only attribute outside `AssemblyInfo.cs` is one of our own:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class OurAttribute_C : System.Attribute
{
    ...
```

I did a diff between this project file and another project file I'm testing, and saw nothing obvious.  Same with the AssemblyInfo files.

I know I can manually create the tests without the tool, but why does VS2010 think that this project is a unit test project?

In searching for this I found a lot of complaints about the feature being entirely missing from VS2012 beta, I have the feature in other projects just not this one.  A couple places had related complaints, but no answers.

Similar (slightly different) question with no answer:  [Unit test generation error in Visual studio website project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854035/unit-test-generation-error-in-visual-studio-website-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you created the "test" project, did you choose a testing project type?

In the csproj, There is a tag called `ProjectTypeGuids` that gives the project a type or list of types for the IDE to understand what IDE tooling to use. You can edit it manually in the csproj.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs) is a non-definitive list of GUIDS

Easiest thing would be to just kill that project and create a new project from the correct template.

Comment: No, this project is not supposed to be a test project, it is a class library I wish to test.  Project properties, Application, Output type is `Class Library`.

Comment: Killing the project and starting over seems to work, but it does not solve the mystery of why.

Comment: Might be it: `<ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>`

Comment: Very possible. Somehow those id's weren't properly applied. Those Ids are how VS knows what context menus and tooling to use.

Comment: That first GUID matches one in a test project I've just created here. Googling for it brings up several results about test projects, including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009943/how-does-visual-studio-mstest-identify-test-projects

Comment: I'll accept the answer for being on the right track even though the question was misunderstood and I think the answer could have been better documented.